# Android Gradle Plugin `registerTransform` is no longer public for plugin developers in 4.1.x and above

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

For AGP 4.1.x / 4.2.0-alpha16, they don't have public  `BaseExtension#registerTransform(...)` method, the new `ApplicationExtension.kt` doesn't export it as well.

Though it still works with 4.0.0 and below, but in 4.1.x and above the BaseExtension has been changed to package access only.

May I know if any replacement for this API? If this is intentional, can someone explain why to do that?

Much thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I sorted out by a workaround below, but I'm not gonna pick it up as the final answer... will keep it open to see if any other elegant approaches could have.

```
package com.android.build.gradle 

import com.android.build.api.transform.Transform
import org.gradle.api.Project

/**
 * Note the package name above, because `BaseExtension` has package access modifier,
 * so we can just forward the method invocation by using a jump class of the same package with `BaseExtension`.
 */
class BaseExtensionExport {

    fun registerTransform(project: Project, transform: Transform, vararg dependencies: Any) {
        val baseExt = project.extensions.findByType(BaseExtension::class.java)
        if (baseExt == null) {
            project.logger.error("Could not find BaseExtension in current project \"${project.name}\"")
            throw IllegalArgumentException()
        }
        baseExt.registerTransform(transform, dependencies)
    }

}
```

Update: I find `project.extensions.findByType(AppExtension::class.java)!!.registerTransform(...)` still works.